# Why do I have to import R class when I use resource in a non-root package?

Tags: android

Whenever I want to use any resource element in the non-root package, I have to import my own `R class` (not Android R class). For example,

Root package `com.example.test` and a file `Main.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

No need to import `R class`.

When I create another package, `com.example.test.something` and a new class in there `Something.java`, I have to import my own `R.class`

```
import com.example.test.R;

//...other code...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

This happens automatically when I move a Java file from root to non-root package.

Why is this so important?

Comment: Your `R` class lives in your application package `com.example.test` -- check out it's package declaration. If you want to reference it from any other package, you need to import it or fully qualify its name, like any other class.

Comment: @PhilippReichart Thanks! Can you post a reply so that I can mark it as an answer?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `R` class lives in your application package `com.example.test` -- check out it's package declaration. If you want to reference it from any other package, you need to import it or fully qualify its name, like any other class.